# Object Reference not set error while trying to set the visiblity of grid

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, reference, grid

I was trying to set the visiblity of a Grid from code behind.

```
grdStopTimeOut.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
```

I have declared this grid in XAML and have set the visiblity to Visible.

```
<Grid Name="grdTimeTStopCondition"  Visibility="Hidden" Margin="0,29,0,-6">
```

Somehow when the application runs the grid is coming as nothing and the exceptions is thrown.
Anybody have any idea why it is happening??

XAML File

```
<Page x:Class="Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
  Title="Page1">
<Grid>
    <ComboBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="cmbStopConditions" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="86" SelectedIndex="0">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Expression"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Manual"></ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <Grid Name="grdStopTimeOut" Visibility="Visible" >
        <Label Content="Timeout" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="lblTimeout_stopcond" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,29,0,0" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="txtStopTimeout" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="30" Margin="60,29,0,0" />
        <Label Content="secs" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="lblTimeoutSec_stopCond" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="39" Margin="105,24,0,0" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

CodeBehind

```vb
Class Page1 

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
Private Sub cmbStopConditions_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs) Handles cmbStopConditions.SelectionChanged
    Dim item As ComboBoxItem = TryCast(cmbStopConditions.SelectedItem, ComboBoxItem)
    If item IsNot Nothing Then
        If Convert.ToString(item.Content) = "Expression" Then
            grdStopTimeOut.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible
        ElseIf Convert.ToString(item.Content) = "Manual" Then
            grdStopTimeOut.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Hidden
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

regards,

SKB

Comment: Have you tried not setting the visibility in the markup and only in the code behind?

Comment: What does the CodeBehind look like.. perhaps you are Initializing the Component incorrectly

Comment: @Daniel Casserly Yes i have tried that. But same error!!!

Comment: @DJKRAZE In my codebehind i'm setting the visiblity of this grid based on a dropdown selection. I have another grid , which i'm setting the visiblity is working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit:** The handler can occur before the grid is initialized, so a null-check is in order.

Are you calling this before `InitializeComponent`? That for one would explain the lack of a reference because all the fields are hooked up with the named controls in that method.

Comment: Yes i'm doing that. I have another grid in the same file which is not throwing any error when i set the visiblity!!!

Comment: @Swa: And you did not null the reference somehwere and the reference is created by the XAML and not you?

Comment: Can you post the necessary code there has to be something that you are not setting correctly or that you are missing .. could be something as simple as the order of how you are setting the properties ..

Comment: @H.B.   i have added the whole code by editing the question above. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @DJKRAZE  i have added the whole code by editing the question above. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @Daniel i have edited the question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @Swa: Who's Daniel? Anyway, selection changed may occurr right when the control is initialized at that point its children, including the grid are not yet there, so you need to do a null-check.

Comment: @H.B. that's a very good call; if you notice, the `ComboBox` has its `SelectedIndex` set in the XAML. I imagine that initial setting would fire the `SelectionChanged` event before the `Grid` gets initialized.

Comment: @AdamMaras: It does, i encountered this before, it's a bit of a pain.

Comment: @H.B. Hey it worked out...Thank you very much. How do i mark your comment as Answer?I'm new to stackoverflow